# would prefer.......than me

Tags: grammar

''I 'd prefer you to mend your shoes rather than me to buy a new pair for you.''

Can I make the sentence above with ''prefer'' instead of ''would Rather'' without subject matching in the first and second part of the sentence?

İs the sentence above grammatically correct?

Comment: You say "Can I make the sentence above with ''prefer'' instead of ''would Rather'' " but it appears that you've already attempted to do this? unless i'm missing something

Comment: *I **would rather** [that] you mend your shoes **than** [that] I buy a new pair for you*. More idiomatically, perhaps (certainly *shorter*), ***Better** you mend your shoes than I buy you a new pair*.